# mod in gprolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to use the mod operator in gprolog 1.3 and keep getting errors. Here's an example predicate I made to demonstrate the problem:

```
test(N) :- N mod 10.
```

When I query test(2). I get "uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,(mod)/2,test/1)". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: get gprolog 1.4.2! It is has more complete arithmetics than 1.3!

Comment: Tried 1.4.2, still got the same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
test(N,X) :- X is N mod 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not make sense.
In prolog, everything is like a rule. The head and the tail should be a statement.
I don't remember the syntax clearly, but it should be like

```
mod10Is2(N) :- N mod 10 = 2
```

Comment: `N mod 10 =:= 2` or `X is N mod 10`